# WebClient call to REST service works in console app but not in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I am calling a test REST web service that basically takes a string as input, and echoes it back to the caller.  I have the following code, in a C# console app:

```
static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
    string baseAddress = 
    "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Services/OnyxCloudSyncService.svc/pingSync";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
       MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await 
               client.GetAsync("?sampleJson={SAMPLEJSON}");           
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string txtBlock = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
        Console.WriteLine(txtBlock);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    }
}
```

This code runs perfectly. But when I essentially copy the same code into the code-behind for an ASP.NET page, I timeout on the call to the service:

```
using (var SyncClient = new HttpClient())
  {
   string baseAddress = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Services/OnyxCloudSyncService.svc/pingSync";
   SyncClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   SyncClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
           MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   HttpResponseMessage response = await 
          SyncClient.GetAsync("?sampleJson={SAMPLEJSON}");
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
    string txtBlock = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Response.Write(txtBlock);
    Response.End();
   }
   else
   {
    Response.Write("Error Calling service");
    Response.End();
   }
  }
```

The error I get from this page is:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because
the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80.
```

Would there be some type of setup or option I need to set on the WebClient to make it work in the ASP page like it does in the Console App?  I am at a loss as to why this would work in a console app and not in an ASP.NET web page.

Comment: Are you running the console app and the ASP.NET app from the same machine?

Comment: Could you try to hit this code through javascript?

Comment: @mason. Yes, same machine.

Comment: @xxmrlnxx I will try to do this through JS now, it will take a little time to code it up, but I will try, see if it works through the browser.

Comment: @xxmrlnxx I mucked up some ugly JS and it worked.  It even works if I paste the address into Firefox's address bar. Still at a loss as to why the webclient cannot connect on backend C#.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having a problem because the result is not being waited for, the solution might be found on: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

I assume you're using .NET 4.5.
Edit method to be instance, not static since you won't be able to reach `Response` object:

```
async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string baseAddress =
        "http://74.120.219.166/Services/OnyxCloudSyncService.svc/pingSync";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
           MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await
                   client.GetAsync("?sampleJson={SAMPLEJSON}");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string txtBlock = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Response.Write(txtBlock);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Error Calling service");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Run method like: `RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(RunAsync));`
Put `Async="true"` in `Page` directive of your .aspx page.
I tried this approach and it worked as expected.

Comment: This looked so promising, as I was not doing ANY of this for the ASP page.  I did do all of what you said, still got the same error message.  Darn!   Thanks for the points on async in ASP.NET. Appreciated.

Comment: Try using Fiddler to see whether the request is being sent and whether the response is arriving. You can also catch request from your console app and compare it to the request generated and sent from the ASP.NET page. Also check if firewall might be causing this.

Comment: Did it and THAT was the answer.  Hang my head. It was the corporate proxy I was not including as an HttpHandler.  The Console does not use the browser but WebClient does, so that was the mismatch.  Now working perfectly!  Thanks to all for suggestions, thanks Ivan G for important pointers, and the strategy to figure out a forehead-slapping problem.  THANKS!